# as it invests heavily in augmented and virtual reality

Tags: modifiers

What does the boldfaced phrase modify?

> Meta Platforms, the company formerly known as Facebook, had its worst day ever on the stock market Thursday, after reporting a rare profit decline and stagnant user numbers, and delivering a vague assessment of the company’s prospects **as it invests heavily in augmented and virtual reality**.

Comment: It doesn't modify anything. *As* is a conjunction (meaning while/when) and it connects uncertain company’s prospects and its heavy interest in simulated experiences.

Comment: As an adverbial clause, it must modify something.

Comment: What is the company investing **heavily** in? In AI technology/software/user interface, i.e augmented and virtual reality.